# Pinterest widget conflict with jquery tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, widget, pinterest

I am trying to put a Pinterest widget into tabs on my website using jQuery, but it does not display anything. However, when I put it outside the tab it works.

I am using this jQuery code:

```
<script="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and this for Pinterest (the second line is just above the body tag as instructed):

```
<a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://pinterest.com/thisismycyprus/"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

this is the tab code

```
 <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content"><h2>Tab 1</h2><p>Content </p></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"><h2>Tab 2</h2><p><a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://pinterest.com/thisismycyprus/"></a></p></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the markup for your tabs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add script in **`$(window).load(function(){ });`**  check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/4pAqv/)

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
//Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });
});//]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is about Pinterest/JQuery (not jquery tabs)

I had to use the Pinterest feed widget (http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_embed_pin) in a slideshow and I got the same bug : when the div container is `display:none;` at page load, the Pinterest content is empty.

I use `visibility:hidden;` instead on my div container, init my slideshow (which waits 4 seconds before starting), set `display:none;visibility:visible;` and then I can use JQuery `show();` / `hide();`